# Ninject and WCF ServiceAuthorizationManager

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container, wcf-security

Does anyone know how I can inject a repository into a `ServiceAuthorizationManager` subtype in a WCF service?

I am creating a class that extends `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and calls a method in my repository to fetch data from the DB, and I would like the repository to be injected in constructor by Ninject.

However, WCF requires a default parameterless constructor in order to use the `ServiceAuthorizationManager` subtype.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Hy,
For cases like that you can use property injection. Just declare your repository as property with an inject attribute similar to the following pseudo code:

```
    public class MyServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {
         [Inject]
         IYourRepo Repository { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then do a normal resolve of your custom ServiceAuthorizationManager

Comment: when I do this, the property is always null.  I am not sure when the ServiceAuthorizationManager is invoked in the WCF pipeline but doesn't seem like it's getting ahold of the Ninject Kernel in order to resolve my property.  Any ideas?

Comment: If I call Ninject.Web.Common.Bootsrapper().Kernel.Get<IRepo>(), I am able to resolve and use the object correctly.  Don't like this solution as I have new up the bootstrapper.

Comment: btw, i instantiate bootstrapper and resolve my repo in the override of ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(OperationContext)

Comment: yes, i have the following service behavior config: <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType='MyProj.MySvcAuthManager, MyAssembly'/>

Comment: just to clarify, I am able to run the WCF service and invoke it, when I new up a Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper, and use its Kernel.Get() to resolve my repository.  But I feel dirty doing that. :)

Comment: Any luck on this one?  I'm facing the same issue.